# How to change data programmatically before validating occur?

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview

After user inputted data to a cell in datagridview (user press Enter key), how to change data programmatically before validating occur?

Please help me!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to change the data before validating occurs? Isn't changing the data *part of validation*?

Comment: I want to change format of inputted value of user. User will input 'dd/MM/yyyy', but corrected format is 'MM/dd/yyyy'

Comment: The correct format for a date is a DateTime object. The .Net Framework can allow users to work in their own, culture specific, formats while you store them without regard. In general, using DateTime where you need dates will automatically translate to the user's specified culture. Avoid string representations of dates in code, strings should only be supplied to and from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use CellValidating Event.

- Event Documentation
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx
- Walk-through of how to use this event (as part of other validation stuff)
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc.aspx

*Disclaimer:*
I'm assuming you are doing windows forms as no ASP.NET tag in there.

Comment: I would have suggested the same thing, except the question is how to do it "before validating occur[s]".

Comment: Putting code in here precedes any built-in validation (it even allows to cancel it because it happens before). If the validation is already in the event handler, then adding a line to the beginning of the event handler function will come before it as well.